# Connect to Windows Server 2012 with valid client certificate only?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

With linux you can issue a certificate and put it into putty and disable password login.

I think this is a great way to stop pesky bots hammering RDP login the whole time.

*I have noticed on the Start SSL website, they generate a certificate for you, which gets installed onto your browser and you don't need to type in a password to login, as long as you have that certificate in the browser.*

Is it possible to connect to RDP using certificate authentication from the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes but you will need to install and configure your Remote Desktop Session host to use a [Remote Desktop Gateway](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12184.deploying-rd-gateway-using-a-scenario-based-deployment.aspx) to do it.

Once you are using a Remote Desktop Gateway you can set up [Remote Desktop Connection Authorization Policies (RD CAPs)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731544.aspx) and [Desktop Resource Authorization Policies (RD RAPs)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730630.aspx) in those you can set things up like requiring that a connecting machine has a client certificate (per machine or per user).

Comment: Thanks - Do you know if it is possible to configure all this on a single machine?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes you can, but it requires a domain to work so that machine will also need to be a domain controller or already joined to a domain that has a domain controller.

Comment: It is defiantly the right direction. To bad its such a nightmare to setup. It easier for me to write my own app that scans the event log and adds firewall rules against the attacker, than setup a certificate based login.. *sigh*